# theme Omega 3 - Use of the Regions

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

you are familiar theme of Omega 3? I have just finished creating a sub-theme and I configured the regions that I need on a page suitable for my content type.

I joined two regions, in which I would like the content that I would like to take with php from my content type.

[image]

But at this point I lies the dilemma. As with the other themes I used a single page .tpl.php with inside the div block to control the layout now how do I break the contents of the content type in different regions?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Display Suite.  You can arrange different parts of your content types into different theme regions.

http://drupal.org/project/ds